# Redirect to specific page when criteria met

Tags: forms, redirect

I'm working on the form that will redirect user after entering their zip code in text box for this examples when they Enter

```
11111 and 22222 they will redirected to google.com
33333 and 44444 they will redirected to yahoo.com
55555 and 66666 they will redirected to bing.com
```

**Here's my redirect_form.php**

```
<form method="post" id="#form" action="redirect_form.php" >
        <input type='text' name="zip" id="zip" placeholder='Enter Your Zip Code'/>      
        <input type='submit' id='btn' name="submit" Value='Submit' /><br />             
    <?php
        include "include/redirect.php";
    ?>  
    </form>
```

**And Here's my redirect.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
            if($zip =='11111' || $zip =='22222')
        {           
          //To redirect form on a particular page
            header("Location:http://www.google.com");
        }
            else if($zip =='33333' || $zip =='44444')
        {           
          //To redirect form on a particular page
            header("Location:http://www.yahoo.com");
        }
        else if($zip =='55555' || $zip =='66666')
        {           
          //To redirect form on a particular page
            header("Location:http://bing.com");
        }
        else{
            ?><span><?php echo "Please enter your Zip code.....!!!!!!!!!!!!";?></span> <?php
         }      
    }
?>
```

But after I tested my form, for example I enter 11111 it gives me this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/mighty1/public_html/epic/redirect_form/redirect_form.php:12) in /home2/mighty1/public_html/epic/redirect_form/include/redirect.php on line 8
```

The line no.8 in redirect.php is `header("Location:http://www.yahoo.com");`

Can someone help me :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

your redirect form is returning content, which requires headers to be sent.  You need to change the form action to be include/redirect.php and remove it from being included.

Comment: Thank you Burrito, but when trying to do that the form won't work at all. Here's the live URL http://goo.gl/Qqxxvx

Comment: sorry I speed answered this without fully reading where redirect.php was being included from.  the action should be action="include/redirect.php" as the php file you want to interact with is in a seperate folder.  You shouldnt post to the same file in this instance as this file is already returning something to the browser (the form) and then it includes the redirect.php

You could also move the check for $_POST to the very top of this page and then exit after the redirect to ensure it works.